# Find expectation of a probablity distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

There're k balls in a bag, each one with a different colour. Draw one ball from the bag randomly each time, then put the ball back.

Let random variable X = the number of balls to draw until all k colours have been seen. Find E(X).

Please help me with this question, thanks!

Comment: See this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

This is the "[coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)".  As the Wikipdia article explains, the expected value is $k$ times the $k$th harmonic number:
$$
k\left( 1 + \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 + \cdots + \frac 1 k \right).
$$